# How to convert a numeric variable to a character variable in SELECT statement (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, char

```
SELECT *
   variable1,
   variable2,
   variable3,
   variable4
FROM table
```

I wanna transform the variable1 from a numeric variable to a character variable, and I'm trying this options:

```
SELECT *
   variable1 AS CHAR(variable1),
   variable2,
   variable3,
   variable4
FROM table
```

And I'm trying this other code:

```
SELECT *
   variable1 AS CONVERT(variable1, CHAR),
   variable2,
   variable3,
   variable4
FROM table
```

But it seems that's not the correct syntax.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(variable1,CHAR) AS variable1,
   variable2,
   variable3,
   variable4
FROM table
```